# How to sort a query by date outside an Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm wanting to make my bike maintenance order listing return the most important urgencies `(urgency_level)` (`Emergency`, `Very urgent`...) first based on the old request dates (`date_solicitation`) As far as I know it's not working because it's always prioritizing the urgencies first with the misordered dates, I tried to do everything in the same query and it didn't work so I came to the conclusion that it's necessary to do an ordering of dates outside of that query.

```
    $queue_maintenance  = QueueMaintenance::orderBy('urgency_level','desc')
                        ->where('type_solicitation', 'First solicitation')
                        ->where('status', 'Waiting for request')
                        ->paginate(10);
    
    $queue_maintenance->sort(function($a, $b) {
        if ($a->urgency_level == $b->urgency_level) {
            return strcmp($a->date_solicitation, $b->date_solicitation);
        }
        return $b->urgency_level - $a->urgency_level;
    });
```

Comment: You can't use `orderBy('urgency_level','desc')->orderBy('date_solicitation','asc')`?

Comment: @StewieSWS this not work.

Comment: Is `urgency_level` an integer, or a varchar field?

Comment: urgency_level is an integer.